# R: interaction between continuous and categorical vars in 'isat' regression ('gets' package)

Tags: r

I want to calculate the differential response of y to x (continuous) depending on the categorical variable z.

In the standard lm setup:

```
lm(y~ x:z)
```

However, I want to do this while allowing for Impulse Indicator Saturation (IIS) in the 'gets' package. However, the following syntax produces an error:

```
isat(y, mxreg=x:z, iis=TRUE)
```

The error message is of the form:

"Error in solve.qr(out, tol = tol, LAPACK = LAPACK) : 
  singular matrix 'a' in 'solve"

1: In x:z :
  numerical expression has 96 elements: only the first used

2: In x:z :
  numerical expression has 96 elements: only the first used"

How should I modify the syntax?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, alas, `isat` doesn't provide the same functionality as `lm` on categorical/character variables, nor on using `*` and `:`. We hope to address that in a future release.

In the meantime you'll have to create distinct variables in your dataset representing the interaction. I guess something like the following...

```
    library(gets)
    N <- 100
    x <- rnorm(N)
    z <- c(rep("A",N/4),rep("B",N/4),rep("C",N/4),rep("D",N/4))
    e <- rnorm(N)
    y <- 0.5*x*as.numeric(z=="A") + 1.5*x*as.numeric(z=="B") - 0.75*x*as.numeric(z=="C") + 5*x*as.numeric(z=="D") + e

    lm.reg <- lm(y ~ x:z)

    arx.reg.0 <- arx(y,mxreg=x:z)

    data <- data.frame(y,x,z,stringsAsFactors=F)
    for(i in z[duplicated(z)==F]) {
      data[[paste("Zx",i,sep=".")]] <- data$x * as.numeric(data$z==i)
    }

    arx.reg.1 <- arx(data$y,mxreg=data[,c("x","Zx.A","Zx.B","Zx.C")])
    isat.1 <- isat(data$y,mc=TRUE,mxreg=data[,c("x","Zx.A","Zx.B","Zx.C")],max.block.size=20)
```

Note that as you'll be creating dummies for each category, there's a chance those dummies will cause singularity of your matrix of explanatory variables (if, as in my example, `isat` automatically uses 4 blocks). Using the argument `max.block.size` enables you to avoid this problem.

Let me know if I haven't addressed your particular point.